# Using VBA to Import multiple text files with different delimiters

Tags: vba, excel

UPDATED CODE AND ISSUES (5/9/2018 1:53PM Eastern)

I am encountering problems trying to import multiple data text files into a fixed worksheet ("Raw Data") using two different delimiters. I am using Application.GetOpenFilename to allow the user to select multiple text files from a folder. The files contain a header row which is semicolon delimited, then several lines of data which is comma delimited. In a single text file, this format can be repeated several times (this is an inspection log file which records and appends data to the same text file for each inspection run, i.e. header line1, some rows of data, header line 2, more rows of data, header line 3, more rows of data, etc.)

I've tried a few approaches to solve this based on other examples I've found on StackOverflow.com but I can't seem to successfully mesh the solutions together to come up with a solution that imports single or multiple text files with two different delimiters within each file. I cannot change the format or content of the original text files, so I can't search and replace different delimiters to a single delimiter.

Here are the remaining issues I'm running into with the attached VBA code:

When importing more than one text file, a blank line is inserted between the files which breaks the .TextToColumns section. It is also asking to replace existing data when importing the second file selected. **Is there a more efficient or better way to import data from multiple text files using both commas and semicolons as delimiters?**

Within a fixed path on the local hard drive, each new order number creates a new sub-folder to store .txt data files (i.e. C:\AOI_DATA64\SPC_DataLog\IspnDetails\123456-7). **Is there a way the user can be prompted to enter a sub-folder name (123456-7) and the VBA script will automatically import all .txt files from this sub-folder, rather than using Application.GetOpenFilename?**

Here is a truncated version of one of the data files I'm trying to import. The actual file does not have spaces between the rows of data. I separated them in this example to clearly show each line in the text file.

```
[StartIspn];Time=04/19/18 12:43:15;User=yeseniar;MachineID=WINDOWS-TEFJCS1;Side=T;DoubleSided;IsOnline=1;IA_Idx=1;SN_Idx=0;IT=0;SPC_Db=1;SPC_Txt=1;TxtFmt=10;E_Rpt=1;D_Img=1;FeedMode=0;

KC17390053F,VIA5F,M North,A8,85.0,45.0,96.0,23.2,9.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,59.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,

KC17390053F,VIA3F,M North,A8,85.0,45.0,96.0,22.3,22.9,0.0,0.0,0.0,59.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,

KC17390053F,FMI1F,S South,A13,12.3,0.0,1.0,3.5,3.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,

KC17390053F,FMI13F,S South,A13,12.3,0.0,1.0,3.5,3.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,

[StartIspn];Time=04/19/18 14:28:10;User=yeseniar;MachineID=WINDOWS-TEFJCS1;Side=B;DoubleSided;IsOnline=1;IA_Idx=1;SN_Idx=0;IT=0;SPC_Db=1;SPC_Txt=1;TxtFmt=10;E_Rpt=1;D_Img=1;FeedMode=0;

KC17390066B,VIA5B,M North,A8,70.0,50.0,92.0,-38.8,-3.7,0.0,0.0,0.0,50.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,

KC17390066B,VIA6B,M North,A8,70.0,50.0,93.0,-37.7,-23.6,0.0,0.0,0.0,50.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,

KC17390066B,FMI12B,S South,A13,4140.4,0.0,2.0,3.5,129.6,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,

KC17390066B,FMI24B,S South,A13,2128.7,0.0,2.0,3.5,119.1,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
```

Here is what I have so far for importing multiple text files:

```
Sub Import_DataFile()

' Add an error handler
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

' Speed up this sub-routine by turning off screen updating and auto calculating until the end of the sub-routine
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

' Define variable names and types
Dim OpenFileName As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim n1 As Long
Dim n2 As Long
Dim fn As Integer
Dim RawData As String
Dim rngTarget As Range
Dim rngFileList As Range
Dim TargetRow As Long
Dim FileListRow As Long
Dim dLastRow As Long
Dim destCell As Range

' Select the source folder and point list file(s) to import into worksheet
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
               FileFilter:="AOI Inspection Results Data Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
               Title:="Select a data file or files to import", _
               MultiSelect:=True)

' Import user selected file(s) to "Raw Data" worksheet
TargetRow = 0
Set destCell = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1")
For n2 = LBound(OpenFileName) To UBound(OpenFileName)
    fn = FreeFile
    Open OpenFileName(n2) For Input As #fn
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing ... " & OpenFileName(n2)

    Do While Not EOF(fn)
        Line Input #fn, RawData
        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & TargetRow).Formula = RawData

    Loop

    Next n2

    Close #fn

 Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1" & ":" & Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Address)

   With rngTarget

    .TextToColumns Destination:=destCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
     TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
     Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar:="|", _
     FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    End With

    Else: MsgBox "The selected file is not the correct format for importing data."

    Exit Sub

    End If

Next

' Create a number list (autofill) in Col A to maintain original import sort order
dLastRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A" & dLastRow).Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1") = "1"
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2") = "2"
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A" & dLastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F1:Q" & dLastRow).NumberFormat = "0.0"

' Auto fit the width of columns for RAW Data
Worksheets("Raw Data").Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Turn screen updating and auto calculating back on since file processing is now complete
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

' Reset to defaults in the event of a processing error during the sub-routine execution
ErrorHandler:
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

' Display a message to the user including the error code in the event of an error during execution
MsgBox "An error number " & Err.Number & " was encountered!" & vbNewLine & _
       "Part or all of this VBA script was not completed.", vbInformation, "Error Message"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You start your sub with error handling, but quickly establish `On Error Resume Next` (twice, actually), and never revert to `On Error GoTo 0`. You're going to have a hard time debugging this with those conditions.

Comment: @dwirony So much easier to just close your eyes to errors than having to deal with them.

Comment: @dwirony I disabled the On Error lines when running the module. The On Error Resume Next instances are required to avoid stopping with an error condition if the network path or folder path doesn't exist on the user's PC.

Comment: @Andreas My eyes weren't closed to avoid dealing with errors. The On Error lines are added to avoid faults when the user's PC doesn't have access to certain file paths that I have defined as default directories, but enables them to go manually find a file.

Comment: @JRN0504 Right, and that's fine, but once they've selected the file you need to turn your error handling back on by re-implementing your line of `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many questions... Let me give some hints.

1. Prompting the user for working directory :

   ```
   Dim fDlg As FileDialog      ' dialog box object
   Dim sDir As String          ' selected path
   Dim iretval As Long         ' test

   Set fDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   sDir = conDEFAULTPATH   ' init
   With fDlg
       .Title = "Select a Folder"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .InitialFileName = sDir
       iretval = .Show
       If iretval = -1 Then sDir = .SelectedItems(1)
   End With
   Set fDlg = Nothing              ' drop object

   If sDir = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Invalid directory"
   Else
        If Right$(Trim$(sDir), 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then _
             sDir = Trim$(sDir) & Application.PathSeparator' append closing backslash to pathname
   End If
   ```
2. Collecting files to a buffer

   ```
   Dim FileBuf(100) as string, FileCnt as long
   FileCnt=0
   FileBuf(FileCnt)=Dir(sDir & "*.txt")
   Do While FileBuf(FileCnt) <> vbnullstring
          FileCnt = FileCnt + 1
          FileBUf(FileCnt) = Dir
   Loop
   ```
3. Reducing number of delimiters: simply use replace

   ```
   RawData = Replace(RawData, ";", ",")
   ```
4. For the blank line I have no clue, though it might be a result of a blank line in the source file, maybe the EOF. So what if you check the line before copying:

   ```
   If len(trim(RawData)) > 0 Then 
       TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
       Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & TargetRow) = RawData
   End If
   ```

Please note that I've removed `.Formula`. You are working with values.

5. For setting target range: You should omit `.Address`. For selecting last cell in a range, you should use `.End(xlUp)` this way:

   ```
   Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1" & ":" & Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1").End(xlUp))
   ```

I prefer using direct cell references, so - as you exactly know the last row - I would do it this way:

```
Set rngTarget =  Worksheets("Raw Data").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(TargetRow, 2))
```

Good Luck!